# Using IT8.7/2 target for camera calibration

Tags: color-management

I got interested in colour calibration of my input devices. I am not a pro, the purpose is to achieve good colour preservation in family archive digitization effort. So cost is a factor.

For my scanners, I bought an IT8.7/2 target from [Wolf Faust](http://www.colorreference.de/targets/index.html). Now I want to repeat the exercise with the camera, and when I look up inexpensive targets, internet comes up with something like Calibrite Colorchecker Classic Mini. IT8.7 is never mentioned. Wolf's site does mention IT8.7 for cameras too, but the title of the page still reads "IT 8.7 Scanner Calibration Targets". So I wonder:

1. Why does everyone seem to be using those 24/48 colour targets when IT8.7 contains 288 colours? Why is IT8.7 called a scanner calibration target, not just a colour calibration target?
2. Why does Wolf Faust offer a special target for cameras? Is it just the size?

FWIW, I am going to take pictures of relatively small objects (not portraits or landscapes) so a 10x15 cm target  can be resolved quite well.

Comment: "> family archive digitization effort."

does it mean you're working with transmissive or reflective material or a bit of both?

Comment: @Nomaru, reflective only. Paper documents and photos from between 1910s and 1980s.

Comment: I have yet to do the profile comparison between one generated with a reflective 24 or 48-patch card and one off of an IT8.7 transmissive target. If you look at `dcamprof` documentation and even `argyllcms`, you'll also see it's "quite easy" to print your own complex reflective target. Getting it measured is a different story, if you don't have a spectrophotometer handy.